# Laptop - Display parts turning yellow intermittently

Tags: laptop, laptop-display

I have got a laptop that lately is giving me a hard time.

Here is a demo gif

[image: yellow screen]

**any idea on why this is happening?**

I haven't dropped or hit the laptop, I just turned it on, and this appeared.

I also tried to reboot it, without luck.

Comment: Is the yellow disappearing when you touch it? It could just be a slightly loose connector behind the screen.

Comment: @Mokubai No sorry, it's not clear from the video. I'm just pointing at it, not touching it. The yellow appears and disappears indipendently

Comment: Seems like the software display overexposed areas. Check for such options

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the intermittent nature of it that looks like one of three potential problems.

1. a loose cable between your main board and the display,
2. the display itself (or it's inbuilt controller) has become defective or
3. your GPU has a dry joint at its output to the display.

Number 1 is probably easiest to deal with, and most likely problem, but would mean dismantling your laptop.  As it could be a connection at either the display side or your motherboard side it is going to be an annoying fix to say the least.

The other two options need highly specialised help and is likely to cost more to fix.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to hook up the laptop to an external display so I can check if it is the display or the GPU